# ayuda me sale error en donde aparecen los asteriscos (soy nuevo en java) es en la plataforma eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class TablaDeMultiplicar {
    private int numMax;
    private int numTabla;


    public TablaDeMultiplicar() {
        this.numMax=0;
        this.numTabla=0;
    }

    public TablaDeMultiplicar (int m, int n) {
        this.numMax=m;
        this.numTabla=n;
    }

    public void setNumTabla(int n) {
        this.numTabla=n;
    }

    **public void GeneradorTabla() {**
         int i=1; {
    }    
            System.out.println(this.numTabla * + i +"="+this.numTabla*i);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema con esta linea

```
public void GeneradorTabla() {
         int i=1; {
    }    
            System.out.println(this.numTabla * + i +"="+this.numTabla*i);

    }
```

es que estas abriendo { } despues de declarar la variable `int i = 1` , no hace falta ya que el primero que tiene el metodo engloba todo

te deberia quedar asi

```
public void GeneradorTabla() {
         int i=1; 

            System.out.println(this.numTabla * + i +"="+this.numTabla*i);

    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias 
ya lo hice aunque me sigue aparecioendo error
porque le soy en ejecutar y si me compila bien 
pero me sale una x
y me subbraya la palabra GeneradorTabla

Comment: que error te aparece?

Comment: sii 
bueno si me compila bien pero me sale una x y me subbraya la palabra GeneradorTabla

Comment: que te dice si pones el puntero por encima de generadortabla?

Comment: bueno en la clase has de cuenta que me aparece una equis y cuando le doy haber donde me aparece el error me selecciona GeneradorTabla y me dice que hay un error en la syntaxis

Comment: podrias subir una foto del problema ?